# SSIS export SQL to formatted CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, export-to-csv, flat-file

I am doing exactly what is outlined here:

- [SSIS: Lesson 1 – Export to CSV](https://analytics4all.org/2018/03/10/ssis-lesson-1-export-to-csv/)

But no matter what I do I cannot get my file to open as a "formatted" .csv as shown in this simple.

My .csv files are actually showing the delimiter I choose and the data is not formatted into each column and row.  I am having to do the text to column to get the data aligned.  What am I missing??!! I am using SSIS 2017.

Is this an issue with excel not picking up my delimiters when I try to open the .csv file?

Comment: What does ` the data is not formatted into each column and row` mean? Edit your question to include a sample of what the output file contains. Are you using the sample data and structure from the example or are you using your own table(s)?

Comment: By that I mean that I would like my csv file data is formatted just like a regular excel file is.  Columns and rows of data, not all data in the first cell and needing to use text to column. So for example in the sample image on the link I referenced, the data is arranged with headers in separate cells across the first row and data for each column in separate cells, not everything exported to the first cell.

Comment: Show the data. Right click on the file and select Open with other and find Notepad. Copy paste into your question

Comment: if your CSV file column is split by comma and wrapped by double quotes, then should be Okay. better show us your output file screen shot then we know the issue.

Comment: I think everything is fine and he has an issue with Excel not doing text to columns properly. Go to Data...TextToColumns and choose delimited and whatever delmiter you chose (usually a comma). This will save for future use and will occur anytime you open a csv or paste comma delimted data.

Comment: It turns out that my issue was with my package somehow setting my flat file to Fixed Width.  Fixing that and setting it to delimited and using a carriage return for the header and comma delimiter allowed my file to be recognized automatically by excel.  Issue resolved.